# Regular Expression Validation For Indian Phone Number and Mobile number

Tags: regex, phone-number

I want to validate Indian phone numbers as well as mobile numbers. The format of the phone number and mobile number is as follows:

For land Line number

```
03595-259506
03592 245902
03598245785
```

For mobile number

```
9775876662
0 9754845789
0-9778545896
+91 9456211568
91 9857842356
919578965389
```

I would like the regular expression in one regex. I have tried the following regex but it is not working properly.

```
{^\+?[0-9-]+$}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For land Line Number

```
03595-259506
03592 245902
03598245785
```

you can use this

```
\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}
```

---

NEW for all ;)

```
OLD: ((\+*)(0*|(0 )*|(0-)*|(91 )*)(\d{12}+|\d{10}+))|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}
NEW: ((\+*)((0[ -]*)*|((91 )*))((\d{12})+|(\d{10})+))|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}

9775876662
0 9754845789
0-9778545896
+91 9456211568
91 9857842356
919578965389

03595-259506
03592 245902
03598245785
```

this site is useful for me, and maby for you .;)http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: When I am using this regex in JS, it showing error " Invalid regular expression: /^((+*)((0[ -]*)*|((91 )*))((d{12})+|(d{10})+))|d{5}([- ]*)d{6}$/: Nothing to repeat " .can you please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 17):

Use the following regex

```
^(\+91[\-\s]?)?[0]?(91)?[789]\d{9}$
```

This will support the following formats:

1. 8880344456
2. +918880344456
3. +91 8880344456
4. +91-8880344456
5. 08880344456
6. 918880344456

Comment: @Ajay update regex to : ^(\+91[\-\s]?)?(\91[\-\s]?)?[0]?(91)?[123456789]\d{9}$) for validating 91-8883044456 if required in your case

Answer (score 10):

This works really fine:

```
\+?\d[\d -]{8,12}\d
```

Matches:

```
03598245785
9775876662
0 9754845789
0-9778545896
+91 9456211568
91 9857842356
919578965389
987-98723-9898
+91 98780 98802
06421223054
9934-05-4851
WAQU9876567892
ABCD9876541212
98723-98765
```

Does NOT match:

```
2343
234-8700
1 234 765
```

Comment: This regex is accepting these no also: 
(@5094 10574

Answer (score 7):

for mobile number:

```
const re = /^[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
```

Comment: This seems like a useful addition relative to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351672/3025856), which is only for landline formats. But why is this preferred over e.g., [@parth’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37412787/3025856), which claims to support both landline _and_ mobile formats?

Comment: Also, it’d be useful to add the test cases you evaluated this against, as other answers have done, to help demonstrate the scope of formats it will cover.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following for one of my python project

Regex

```
(\+91)?(-)?\s*?(91)?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{4})
```

Python usage

```
re.search(re.compile(r'(\+91)?(-)?\s*?(91)?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{4})'), text_to_search).group()
```

Explanation

```
(\+91)? // optionally match '+91'
(91)?   // optionally match '91'
-?      // optionally match '-'
\s*?    // optionally match whitespace
(\d{3}) // compulsory match 3 digits
(\d{4}) // compulsory match 4 digits
```

Tested & works for

```
9992223333
+91 9992223333
91 9992223333
91999 222 3333
+91999 222 3333
+91 999-222-3333
+91 999 222 3333
91 999 222 3333
999 222 3333
+919992223333
```

Comment: update your answer.. ```(\+91)?(-)?\s*?(91)?\s*?([6-9]{1}\d{2})-?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{4})```.. Indian numbers start with either 6,7,8 or 9..

Answer (score 4):

For both mobile & fixed numbers: `(?:\s+|)((0|(?:(\+|)91))(?:\s|-)*(?:(?:\d(?:\s|-)*\d{9})|(?:\d{2}(?:\s|-)*\d{8})|(?:\d{3}(?:\s|-)*\d{7}))|\d{10})(?:\s+|)`

Explaination:

```
(?:\s+|)                    // leading spaces
((0|(?:(\+|)91))            // prefixed 0, 91 or +91
(?:\s|-)*                   // connecting space or dash (-)
(?:(?:\d(?:\s|-)*\d{9})|    // 1 digit STD code & number with connecting space or dash
(?:\d{2}(?:\s|-)*\d{8})|    // 2 digit STD code & number with connecting space or dash
(?:\d{3}(?:\s|-)*\d{7})|    // 3 digit STD code & number with connecting space or dash
\d{10})                     // plain 10 digit number
(?:\s+|)                    // trailing spaces
```

I've [tested](http://regexr.com/3dfsh) it on following text

```
9775876662
0 9754845789
0-9778545896
+91 9456211568
91 9857842356
919578965389

0359-2595065
0352 2459025
03598245785
07912345678
01123456789
sdasdcsd
+919898101353
dasvsd0 
+91 dacsdvsad
davsdvasd

0112776654
```

Answer (score 0):

All mobile numbers in **India** start with **9**, **8**, **7** or **6**. Now, there is a chance that you are not bothering about the prefixes (+91 or 0). If this is your scenario, then you can take the help from the website [regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/93470) or you can use **r'^(+91[-\s]?)?[0]?(91)?[789]\d{9}$'**

And if you want to validate the Phone number with prefixes(+91 or 0) then use : **r'^[6-9]\d{9}$'**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression like this.

> /^[(]+\ ++\d{2}[)]+[^0]+\d{9}/

Comment: This is matching `(((((((((                    12)))))))))))))))))))))))))*$ù^^<q!§à@çè"é """123456789jsqfh khe alkjlkjrh erj kjhklerjaht lekjarhtlkjrt` not sure it is a valid phone number.

Answer (score 0):

**For Indian Mobile Numbers**

Regular Expression to validate 11 or 12 (starting with 0 or 91) digit number

```
String regx = "(0/91)?[7-9][0-9]{9}";

String mobileNumber = "09756432848";

check 

if(mobileNumber.matches(regx)){
   "VALID MOBILE NUMBER"
}else{
   "INVALID MOBILE NUMBER"
}
```

You can check for 10 digit mobile number by removing `"(0/91)?"` from the regular expression i.e. regx

Comment: Now, Mobile numbers can start with digit "6".

Answer (score 0):

you can implement following regex
regex = '^[6-9][0-9]{9}$'

Answer (score 0):

```
r'\+?(91?|0?)[\-\s]?[3-9]\d{3}[\-\s]?\d{6}$'
```

explanation

1. +?       # Start with plus sign or not
2. (91?|0?) # Followed by 91 or 0 or none of them
3. [-\s]?  # Followed by either - or space, or none of them
4. [3-9]    # followed by any number from 3 between 9
5. \d{3}    # followed by any three digits
6. \d{6}    # followed by any six digits
7. $        # specify string should stop at that point

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use Regex Like This:

```
   ^[0-9\-\(\)\, ]+$
```

Answer (score -1):

All Landline Numbers and Mobile Number

^[\d]{2,4}[- ]?[\d]{3}[- ]?[\d]{3,5}|([0])?(\+\d{1,2}[- ]?)?[789]{1}\d{9}$

Answer (score -2):

```
var phonereg = /^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/;
```

Comment: Please explain the regex for future visitors.

Comment: Can you please explain your code? it's not self explanatory