# Validate field to indian mobile number

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have input field that should except only 10 digits which contain 0-9 numbers, and a option +91 or 0 at the start. SO i have to restrict my input field to 13 number including +91 as optional.

This field should only accept numbers here is what I have done but its failing to validate please suggest me if any changes. I need to validate using html-5 reghular expression.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="13" pattern="\ *\+?\d+"  required 
name="" title="Only numbers and '+' are accepted" id="" class="register-input-val form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Mobile Number" >
```

Here is my JSFIDDLE[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cqynLs8c/)

```
The number format will look like this
+91XXXXXXXXXX +91 and 10 digits
0XXXXXXXXXX 10 digits with 0
```

Comment: can you include the exact number format you wanted.

Comment: @NewbeeDev added format

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Validation For Indian Phone Number and Mobile number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351553/regular-expression-validation-for-indian-phone-number-and-mobile-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll prefer using regular expression to validate.

```
((\+*)((0[ -]+)*|(91 )*)(\d{12}|\d{10}))|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}
```

See [the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wisdomabioye/rxx9f4us/)

```css
body {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    Font-size: 10pt;
}
span {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" maxlength="13" pattern="((\+*)((0[ -]+)*|(91 )*)(\d{12}+|\d{10}+))|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}"  required 
name="" title="Only numbers and '+' are accepted" id="" class="register-input-val form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Mobile Number" >
<button type="submit">Validate</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: i NEED IT TO INCLUDE IN PATTERN OF HTML-5

Comment: This pattern accepts Indian numbers as well as other than numbers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xLbbr26o/ PLease try here in html-5 and see yourself

Comment: @Sudarshan Kalebere, check out the fiddle here. It's working fine. [Phone number validation on JSfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Wisdomabioye/rxx9f4us/13/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression

((+*)((0[ -]+)*|(91 )*)(\d{12}+|\d{10}+))|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}

hope it works...

Comment: i NEED IT TO INCLUDE IN PATTERN OF HTML-5

Comment: <form action="demo.asp">
Phone: <input type="phone" name="phone" pattern="((+*)((0[ -]+)|(91 ))(\d{12}+|\d{10}+))|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}">
<input type="submit">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Please review this answer. (i.e. [Regular Expression Validation For Indian Phone Number and Mobile number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351553/regular-expression-validation-for-indian-phone-number-and-mobile-number))

Let me know if you have any query regarding this.

Comment: i NEED IT TO INCLUDE IN PATTERN OF HTML-5

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

((+91)|0){1}(\d{10})

Answer (score 0):

add this "^((+91[0-9]{10})|(0[0-9]{10}))$" to your attribute pattern in your input

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" maxlength="13" pattern="^((\+91[0-9]{10})|(0[0-9]{10}))$"  required 
  name="" title="Only numbers and '+' are accepted" id="" class="register-input-val form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Mobile Number" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/4929/)