# Regular Expression for Indian Mobile Phone Number (Java)

Tags: java, regex

In an intermediate output, I'm getting a string like:

```
+91 87774 44444‬ (64 messages):
```

I tried using this regex but it is returning false:

```
(^\\+\\d{2} \\d{5} \\d{5} \\(\\d* \\w*\\):)
```

Can anyone explain me this, and also provide correct answer? I'm using Netbeans IDE.

The message contains a null character at the end, that's why I can not match the pattern...

Comment: Pretty much answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351553/regular-expression-validation-for-indian-phone-number-and-mobile-number

Comment: (^\\+\\d{2} \\d{5} \\d{5} \\(\\d* \\w*\\):)

^ defines that the patter must start at beginning of a new line

\\+ selects the +

\\d indicate Any digit, short for [0-9] so \\{2} means you are searching 0-9 in next two digit 

Same goes for this \\d{5} \\d{5} for next 5 digit then again 5 digit 

* indicates, Occurs zero or more times, is short for {0,}

\w indicates, as metacharacter and used to find a word character.

I am not sure but by using this may be you are skipping every other character \\(\\d* \\w*\\)

Answer (score -1):

```
\+[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{5}\s[0-9]{5}
```

`+` and the numbers thereafter `\+[0-9]{2}`

Space `\s`

Another 5 numbers `[0-9]{5}`

Space `\s`

Last 5 numbers [0-9]{5}

You can use online [Java Regular Expression](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

[image]