# Phone number validation using jQuery validator

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

By form submit using "jQuery validator" for input field validation. I want to validator phone number its working fine but that problem is phone number must start with '+'.

So I am using RegEx

```
/\+[91][0-9]{10}/
```

my jQuery rules is

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
        phoneNumber: {
            matches: "/\+[91][0-9]{10}/",
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10,
            number: true
        }
    }
});
```

That above code is not working, is its correct for add matches field RegEx to jQuery validator

Comment: Can you add list of all possible valid and invalid numbers

Comment: Do you want to validate **Mobile Number**?

Comment: yes 

+(91)(9823543219)
+(91)(9876546719)
+(91)(9823453219)
+(91)(9876523123)

Comment: yes i want to valid only mobile numbers

Comment: Check [regular expression for Indian mobile numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813195/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

is the area code always 91? in your test will only match area codes 9 or 1 followed by 10 numbers, if it is always 91 you can try `/\+91[0-9]{10}/`

if you want to match this
+(91)(9876546719) and +919876546719
you can use

```
/\+\(?91\)?\(?[0-9]{10}\)?/
```