# How to avoid to enter repeated number in input text form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying past few days to solve input number form validation in javascript. The logic user doesn't allow to enter repeated same number like "00000000000", "11111111111". If they enter numbers on text field i have to show error message,

sample code,

```
var mobNumber = $('#phNo').val();

if(mobNumber.match("00000000") || mobNumber.match("1111111")) {
  alert('Please enter valid phone number');
}
```

Comment: Use regex for valid phone numbers

Comment: yes i tried. User can able to enter both mobile and landline numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813195/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-numbers

Comment: Do you mean that a number should not be the same as the previous number or that all 8 digits should not be the same number?

Comment: Regex to find repeating numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507982/regex-to-find-repeating-numbers

Comment: @CaraTilos if i enter first six characters are the same number i have to display error

Comment: @DavidJorHpan it can be any kind of phone numbers like landline or mobile number

Answer (score 2):

You could use following regex `^(\d)\1+$` :

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- `(...)` 1st capturing group
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
- `+` Quantifier, matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any).

See following example:

```js
function test(par){
  if(par.match(/^(\d)\1+$/g)){
    console.log(par + " is not valid");
  }else{
    console.log(par + " is valid");
  }
}

test("11111111");
test("11131111");
test("111a1111");
test("010101010");
test("9999");
```

I hope it helps you. Bye

Comment: looks like the OP wants something inverse, I mean `11111111` should be invalid.

Comment: Oh I could change it, the logic is the same.

Comment: Ok, I simply changed the log messages with "is not valid" when regex match otherwise I print "is valid"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write code like

```
$(document).on('input', '#phNo', function() {
    var mobNumber = $(this).val();
    var res = mobNumber/(mobNumber/10);
    if(res == 111111111) {
      alert('Please enter valid phone number');
    }
});
```

this  is applicable for all numbers and you have to check the max and min length of the input ..

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var checkPhone = function() {
  phone_number = $('#phone').val();
  res = (/^(.)\1+$/.test(phone_number) ? '1' : '0');
  if(res == '1'){
    return 'bad phone number';
  } else {
    return 'good phone number';
  }
}
```

Test it here : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kanzari/7ag2o43f/26/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
var phone = "11111111";
            var phonecount = phone.length;
            var countLength = 0;
            for (var i in phone)
            {
                if(phone.substring(0,1)==phone[i])
                {
                    countLength = countLength + 1;
                }
            }
            if (countLength == phonecount)
            alert("Please enter valid phone number");
```