# Regular expression for an indian mobile number with +91?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for an indian mobile number with +91 as optional before the number

The regEx that I have written is below:

```
^[\+91]?[7-9][0-9]{9}$
```

This isn't working properly, please help.

Comment: Can you post an example string that fails this test?

Comment: Check `webx` answer here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813195/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-numbers

Comment: Probably your issue is related to the `[\+91]` part. If so, try using `[(\+91)]` instead.

Comment: How is it "not working properly"? You need to read up on the meaning of a character set or class (`[]`). `[/+91]` does **not** mean to match `+91`. You could also search for other answers on SO, of which there are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. I've tested it on https://regex101.com/

```
 /^((\+91?)|\+)?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/
```

Comment: This will match `1234567890` which is not a valid number.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about using groups. I have edited your regex and here's what I have written which is working perfectly /^((\+91?)|\+)?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;