# How to validate phone number in HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form and would like to see if the user filled the input with a correct number or not. The number must contains 10 digits and the two first digits should be equal to `05` or `06`. Can anyone help me how to do this in PHP or in JavaScript please?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284533/how-to-set-validation-on-phone-number-in-php) your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phone number validation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358380/phone-number-validation-android)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, You can use regex and javascript to reach those kind of validation or u can find a plugin or a validation lib for that can works depends...

Comment: Hey there. On SO, you're expected to show the code you have, then detail what your expected output/result is vs. what you currently get, plus all error messages, if any. Currently, it looks like you're just asking us to write code for you, which will get your question closed pretty soon. I suggest to check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit yours accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set validation on Phone number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284533/how-to-set-validation-on-phone-number-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments and example phone number that you given, this code will validating number of digits and first two numbers of your country, i just replaced + with 0, for sure they won't enter plus.

```
$tel = '0512345678';

if(preg_match("/^0[5|6][0-9]{8}$/", $tel)) {
    echo "valid";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to validate the phone number on the server or in the client (user's web browser)? In the first case you should use PHP, in the latter case a JavaScript function.

PHP:

```php
function isValidPhoneNumber($number) {
  return preg_match('/^0[5|6][0-9]{8}$/', $number);
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
function isValidPhoneNumber(number) {
  return /^0[5|6][0-9]{8}$/.test(number);
}
```