# Mobile Number Validation for indian mobile

Tags: android, mobile, pattern-matching

am implementing an android application, i want to validate mobile number but nit succeed my code :

```
 final String regexStr = "^(?:(?:\\+|0{0,2})91(\\s*[\\-]\\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\\d{9}$";
final EditText chmobno = (EditText)login.findViewById(R.id.chmobno);
 mb=chmobno.getText().toString();
```

on button click

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if( mb.matches(regexStr)){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Login Sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                login.cancel();
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,TSO_Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Please enter Valid Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

when i enter valid number it goes else part.. please help me to find the error

Comment: this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813195/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-numbers

Comment: which number you tested..send format

Comment: 9496582800 9496582801 9496582802 9496582803 ...tried

Comment: @ Nilesh Rathod i tried but no solution

Comment: @Avinash try this **`((\+*)((0[ -]+)*|(91 )*)(\d{12}+|\d{10}+))|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}`**

Comment: @Avinash numbers are working correctly

Comment: @Avinash check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813226/7666442

Comment: i tried it goes to else part only ? is there any mistake on my code

Comment: it works bro small misatke

Comment: I suggest to use this library https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Answer (score 2):

```
final String regexStr = "^(?:(?:\\+|0{0,2})91(\\s*[\\-]\\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\\d{9}$";
final EditText chmobno = (EditText)login.findViewById(R.id.chmobno);
 mb=chmobno.getText().toString();
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if( mb.matches(regexStr)){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Login Sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                login.cancel();
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,TSO_Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Please enter Valid Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```