# How to validate indian mobile number using Pattern in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, pattern-matching, angular6

As I mentioned in my title I am trying to validate the user entered mobile number is a indian number or not .

For that I have referred a pattern from this [regular expression for Indian mobile numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813195/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-numbers)

But in my case it always returns false.

I want to validate the following .

- number should starts with 6,7,8,9
- must have 10 digits

app.component.html

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="userAddressValidations">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-sm-6">
        <mat-label>10-digit Mobile Number</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="mobileNumber" maxlength="10" (keypress)=_keyPress($event)>
        <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('mobileNumber').hasError('required')">
            Please fill out this field.
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('mobileNumber').hasError('pattern')">
            It is not a valid mobile number.
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class InputErrorStateMatcherExample {
  userAddressValidations: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userAddressValidations = this.formBuilder.group({
      mobileNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[6-9]\d{9}$')]]
    });

  }
  _keyPress(event: any) {
    const pattern = /[0-9]/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
        event.preventDefault();

    }
}
}
```

Stackblitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-validation-eg-4jag5u?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts

can anyone help me to fix it.

Comment: Use `Validators.pattern('[6-9]\\d{9}')`. The `^` and `$` are added automatically.

Comment: post your comment as answer of this question @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Added with some explanations and an alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
Validators.pattern('[6-9]\\d{9}')
```

The `^` and `$` are added automatically when the pattern is set with the help of a string literal. Alternatively, you may use a regex literal notation (then, `^` and `$` are required):

```
Validators.pattern(/^[6-9]\d{9}$/)
```

Note that `^` and `$` play no role in this concrete snippet since you limit the number of input chars with `maxlength="10"` attribute.

See the [resulting regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kb2Jh1/1) and the [updated Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-validation-eg-6wdqb9?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts).

Answer (score 1):

This is most easiest way to validate the Mobile Number in Angular.

```
<input class="input" id="phoneNumber" type="tel" placeholder="Your Mobile number [(ngModel)]="phone_number" pattern="^[7-9][0-9]{9}$" ngModel phone #phone="ngModel" maxlength="10" minlength="10">

  <div class="" *ngIf="phone.touched && !phone.valid">
      <div class="tag" *ngIf="phone.errors.required">Mobile No. is required. 
      </div>
      <div  class="tag" *ngIf=" phone.errors.pattern">Inaild Mobile Number</div>
  </div>
```